# zeroes of tan function

Tags: trigonometry

Currently in preparation for an exam on Separation of variables for PDEs.

And I might have conveniently forgotten the zeroes of tan.

Can I confirm that the zeroes are located at $n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Hint: $$\tan x := \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}.$$

Comment: Zeroes of Sin occurs at $$(n)\pi$$ and Zeros of Cos occurs at $$(n\pi + \pi/2)$$

Comment: I can see what happens when sin is 0. I need a general expression

Comment: So the zeroes of $\tan$ are the same as for $\sin$ and therefore $z_n=n\pi$

Comment: @marwalix Thanks. 
When the exams is around the corner, there's no time to play 'hinting' games for such trivial question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct the zeros of $\tan$ are $n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Zeros of $\tan x$ exist when $\sin x = 0$. This happens when $x = n\pi$ for all  $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.